# Do we have the following equality: $\lim\mu\left(K_{m}\right)=\mu\left(\cap_{m=1}^{\infty}K_{m}\right) $?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $R^n$ and {$K_{m}$} be a sequence of compact sets in $R^n$. Assume that $K_{m+1} \subset K_{m}$ for all $m$. Do we have the following equality: $\lim\mu\left(K_{m}\right)=\mu\left(\cap_{m=1}^{\infty}K_{m}\right)
 $?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: How to make it clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an outline of something more general: The following proposition is true in general, for all (positive) measures:

> If $\mu(A_1) < \infty$ and $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq A_3 \supseteq \dots$, then $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \mu(A_k) = \mu\left(\bigcap_k A_k\right)$$

To prove this, begin by showing that the opposite statement holds:

> If $B_1 \subseteq B_2 \subseteq \dots$, then $\lim_{k \to \infty} \mu(B_k) = \mu(\bigcup_k B_k)$.

This can be shown using the monotonicity of measure. Then apply De Morgan's laws to $$A_1 \setminus \bigcap_k A_k$$

Comment: Why need $K_{n}$ compact?

Comment: @chuyenvien94 The only place that compactness is used is to conclude that one of the sets has finite measure.

Comment: It's my trouble. How to prove it?

Comment: A compact set of $R^n$ is bounded and closed, so it has finite measure.

Comment: @chuyenvien94 Have a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178936/measure-of-a-countable-union-of-sets).